# Computation of final grades in a listview

Tags: c#, listview

This is all of the code i have done so far. The system has a listview that has a column header:

```
subject name | 1st | 2nd | 3rd | 4th | Final Grades
```

If the column 1st to 4th contains value it will compute for the final grade of the student. sum(1st to 4th) / 4 *50 + 50.  if one of the column does not have a value then the user will be prompted and no final grades will be computed.

I am confused on how do i get all the listview value from 1st to 4th then automatically computes the final grade.

PLease help

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    flag = false;

    if (txt_numValue.Text != "")
    {
        char[] entereddata = txt_numValue.Text.ToCharArray();

        foreach (char aChar in entereddata.AsEnumerable())
        {
            if (!Char.IsDigit(aChar))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.", "In the field Numeric Value");
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (txt_numValue.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please do not leave the field, 'Numeric Value', blank.", "Attention!");
        flag = true;
    }

    if (flag == false)
    {
        string period = txt_gradingPeriod.Text;
        string numeric = txt_numValue.Text;
        int cell = 0;

        if (period == "1st") { cell = 1; }
        else if (period == "2nd") { cell = 2; }
        else if (period == "3rd") { cell = 3; }
        else if (period == "4th") { cell = 4; }

        foreach (ColumnHeader header in listView1.Columns)
        {
            if (header.Text == period)
            {
                listView1.Items[0].SubItems[cell].Text = numeric;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to first start off by learning how to step through your code by using the debugger. Then pinpoint which line(s) are causing the issue and report back to us so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have got all the data in your list view you can do something like this,

```
  int sum = 0;           
        foreach (ListViewItem v in listView1.Items)
        {
            bool hasBlank = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < v.SubItems.Count;i++ )
            {
                if (v.SubItems[i].Text == null || v.SubItems[i].Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    //code                      
                    hasBlank = true;
                    break;                        
                }
                else
                {
                    sum += Convert.ToInt16(v.SubItems[i].Text);
                }
            }
            if (!hasBlank)
            {
                string grade="something";
                //formula to calculate grade based on sum.set the result to string grade
                v.SubItems[4].Text = grade;                   
            }
            else
            {
                v.SubItems[4].Text = "has blank";
            }
            sum = 0;
        }
```

This will fill grade if all values are present else a message that it has a blank value.